# PHP parse error on database search result return

Tags: php

I'm trying to get data out of a mysql db and I have the login info saved in another file.  The username is getting sent from my form to the page with the code and i'm getting a

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\waladmin\ipfinder.php on line 31.

I don't understand why its saying that though, everything looks fine.

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php
testinclude('db_login.php');

$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password);
//$con = mysql_connect('10.241.10.40','waladmin','waladmin');
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_select=mysql_select_db($db_database);
if(!db_select)
{
die("Could not select the database. <br />".mysql_error());
}

$select = ' Select ';
$column = ' IP_Address,Workstation,Username ';
$from = ' FROM ';
$tables = ' admintable ';
$where = ' where Username = " & ControlChars.Quote & Username & Username &           ControlChars.Quote & "ORDER BY admintable.Time_Stamp DESC';
$query = $select.$column.$from.$tables.$where;

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!result)
{
die("Could not query the database:  <br />".mysql_error());
}

while($result_row = mysql_fetch_row(($result))){
echo 'Username:  ' . result_row[2] . ' <br /> ';
echo 'Workstation: ' . result_row[2] . ' <br /> ';
echo 'IP Address:  ' . result_row[1] . ' <br /> ';
}
echo $con;
mysql_close($con)   
echo $con;
?>
```

Comment: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change all the `result_row[1/2]` to `$result_row[1/2]`

Comment: That was it!  Brilliant, I can't believe I missed it!

Comment: Now I get Notice: Use of undefined constant db_select - assumed 'db_select' in C:\xampp\htdocs\waladmin\ipfinder.php on line 12

Notice: Use of undefined constant result - assumed 'result' in C:\xampp\htdocs\waladmin\ipfinder.php on line 25

Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\waladmin\ipfinder.php on line 30
Resource id #4

Comment: same thing `if (!db_select)` should be `if (!$db_select)`. and change the line `if(!result)` to `if(!$result)`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `$` in front of several references to `$result_row`. Since PHP sees constants, the `[` is unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in last while loop...you missed $ sign and you also missed semicolumn too...

replace this code with respectives..

```
while($result_row = mysql_fetch_row(($result))){
echo 'Username:  ' . $result_row[2] . ' <br /> ';
echo 'Workstation: ' . $result_row[2] . ' <br /> ';
echo 'IP Address:  ' . $result_row[1] . ' <br /> ';
}
echo $con;
mysql_close($con);
echo $con;
```